# Menu/Recent apps SM-G935W8

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I wonder if there is a way to get the menu button on the recent apps button. If you don't understand, I want to have the same thing as the gt-i9195: long press on the home button opens recent apps; press on recent apps button opens menu.